# How to bind Syncfusion MVC grid to a specific list property in my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I can bind my grid to the whole model, here's an example of one working grid:

```
(Html.EJ().Grid<API_EventListDTO>("EventListGrid")    
                    .Datasource(Model)    
                    .Columns(col =>    
                    {

                        col.Field("EventId").HeaderText("Event ID").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(75).Add();

                        col.Field("EventTypeDescription").HeaderText("Event Description").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(75).Add();

                        col.Field("CreatedOn").HeaderText("Created On").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(75).Add();

                        col.Field("Status").HeaderText("Status").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(75).Add();

                        col.Field("Message").HeaderText("Message").TextAlign(TextAlign.Center).Width(75).Add();
                    }))
```

Model in this case, is `@model List<API_EventListDTO>`.

However now I need to bind a new grid to a specific property of the model which is a list of items. How can I do that? What I need to write in `@(Html.EJ().Grid<API_EventListDTO>("EventListGrid")` and in `.Datasource(Model)`??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to bound the list as dataSource for the grid using Model. Please refer the below sample and code example.

Sample [here](http://files2.syncfusion.com/dtsupport/forum/136963/ze/EJGrid507210542.zip)

```
@model EJGrid.Controllers.HomeController.newclass

@(Html.EJ().Grid<Orders>("FlatGrid")
              .Datasource(Model.empID)
              .AllowPaging()

                    …..

)

[Controller.cs]
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static List<Orders> order = new List<Orders>();
        public static List<EmpID> emp = new List<EmpID>();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<EmpID> emp1 = new List<EmpID>() { new EmpID() { ID = 1, Name = "Ewddada" }};
            List<EmpID> emp2 = new List<EmpID>() { new EmpID() { ID = 2, Name = "Caxada" }};
            List<EmpID> emp3 = new List<EmpID>() { new EmpID() { ID = 3, Name = "Nmbddj" }};
            List<EmpID> emp4 = new List<EmpID>() { new EmpID() { ID = 4, Name = "Mbgfuydf" }};
            List<EmpID> emp5 = new List<EmpID>() { new EmpID() { ID = 5, Name = "Nuhjbsd" }};
            order.Add(new Orders( 1, "VINET", emp1, 32.38, new DateTime(2014, 12, 25), "Reims"));
            order.Add(new Orders( 2, "TOMSP", emp2, 11.61, new DateTime(2014, 12, 21), "Munster"));
            order.Add(new Orders( 3, "ANATER",emp3, 45.34, new DateTime(2014, 10, 18), "Berlin"));
            order.Add(new Orders( 4, "ALFKI", emp4, 37.28, new DateTime(2014, 11, 23), "Mexico"));
            order.Add(new Orders( 5, "FRGYE", emp5, 67.00, new DateTime(2014, 05, 05), "Colchester"));

            newclass newModel = new newclass();
            newModel.empID = emp1;
            newModel.ord = order;
            return View(newModel);

        }
        public class newclass {
            public List<EmpID> empID { get; set; }
            public List<Orders> ord { get; set; }
        }    
    }

[Model class]

  public class Orders
    {
        public Orders()
        {

        }
        public Orders(int orderId, string customerId, List<EmpID> empId, double freight, DateTime orderDate, string shipCity)
        {
            this.OrderID = orderId;
            this.CustomerID = customerId;
            this.EmployeeID = empId;
            this.Freight = freight;
            this.OrderDate = orderDate;
            this.ShipCity = shipCity;
        }
        public int? OrderID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public List<EmpID> EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public double? Freight { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public string ShipCity { get; set; }
    }
    public class EmpID
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In the above code example Orders is the model which contains a property EMPID which is a list of items. In the controller page we have stored the list objects of the Orders and EMPID in a new class objects and passed it as a model. In this way the required list can be accessed using Model parameter in view page.